# tryCatch() funtion in r - How can I save error/warning message?

Tags: r, warnings, message

I am simulating multilevel data and fitting it to various Multilevel models.

I want to make a function that if there is any error (such as "failed to converge" or "singular fit"), I want to save it.

For example, my model is

lmer(y~ x1 + x2 + (1|pid), data=sim_data).

and here are many conditions so various data will be fitted into this model.

How can I save the error or warning message as a whole in the dataframe or list?

(like, first dataset -> no error, second dataset -> converge error...etc)

Comment: Are you using  a for loop to sequence the different fits?

Comment: You can work something with `tryCatch(stop("hello"), error = function(e) e$message)`, but you're probably better of using `purrr::safely()` when creating a new column, which you can then `tidy::unnest_wider()` if relevant.

Comment: yes I am using a for loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a for loop to iterate through the conditions or "various data":

0.Setting up a dummy function that might throw error:

```
dummyfunction <- function(x) {
  if (i == 0) {
    stop("Error occurred")
  }
  return(i * 100)
}
```

1.Preparing a list to receive results

```
result <- list()
```

2.Iterating through different "conditions":

```
for (i in c(-1, 0, 1)) {

  # Using tryCatch to handle errors 
  # that might occur when executing dummyfunction (i.e. put them in the result list)
  #
  result[[as.character(i)]] <- tryCatch(dummyfunction(i),
    error = function(e) e
  )  
  
}
```